# Matlab - Matrix Division by Zero - Zeros and NaNs

Tags: matlab, matrix, bsxfun

I am trying to convert a precision matrix sigmaT to a covariance matrix. I've tried two approaches:

```
covMat = zeros(size(sigmaT));
for i=1:t
    covMat(:, :, i) = eye(D)/sigmaT(:,:,i);
end
```

and

```
covMat = bsxfun(@rdivide, eye(D), sigmaT);
```

Some of the elements in sigmaT are zero, so division by zero occurs. The first loop-based solution keeps the elements where division by 0 occurs as 0, the second approach sets the elements to NaN.

My questions would be: why do they behave differently and how can I change the second one-line approach to behave as the loop-based approach? I believe the latter solution should be significantly faster on large matrices.

Comment: NaN is the correct answer when you divide by zero.

Comment: @Alex `NaN` is okay, but I think that `Inf` or `-Inf` would be more a appropriate output (depending on the sign of the dividend, of course).

Comment: @EitanT what about 0/0? In general division by zero is undefined. Also, infinity is not a real number. We may as well use NaN. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/functions_and_graphs/undefined_indeterminate/v/why-dividing-by-zero-is-undefined

Comment: @Alex 0/0 is indeed `NaN`, but that's an exception. `Inf` at least holds the information about the sign, and also allows a zero result when being the denominator in a fraction with a finite numerator. Obviously `Inf` is an undefined number in MATLAB, but it allows fairly basic limit-calculus when numbers strive to infinity, and that sometimes does have a defined result.

Comment: @EitanT Yes `+Inf`, `-Inf` and `NaN` has more information then just general `NaN`. My point was when you divide by zero, `0` is never the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop based approach is performing matrix division, that is the result for each iteration is the matrix inverse of `sigmaT(:,:,i)`.  You can adjust the loop to perform per-element math by using the `./` operator (instead of `/`).

Your `bsxfun` based approach is performing per-element division, that is each individual element is inverted.  There is no way to use `bsxfun` to perform a matrix operation on each 2D matrix contained in a 3D array.

These answers are very different.  You should use whatever approach is appropriate for your problem.  The performance difference between the two is probably relatively small.